# What is the Difference Between Generic call and .. as Casting in Angular/Typescipt? Especially for HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, casting

I have the Following issue.

Some more expirienced programmers told me to never use generics in http Methods:

```js
public getAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(url);
}
```

And that I should always use:

```js
public getAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get(url) as Observable<User[]>;
}
```

No one can explain why. Its a convention(?), but it is hard to grasp why. Is there any "historical meaning" or is it just for reability?

Comment: Your team set that rule but nobody knows why?

Comment: probably readability; from code purity perspective first call is much more in the spirit of TS.

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes. "Its just a convention" and "we always declare it that way". Maybe someone has a good Idea why you should do it that way. They learned it that way. Nobody knows where this "convention originated from"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although at first sight it might seem like these two notations do the same thing, it's not actually true. By generally type-casting expressions like in your second example, you actually weaken the compiler and might miss type errors that you'd otherwise see.

An example:

```
function copy<T>(object: T): T {
    return {
        ...object
    };
}

class Car {
    armCount = 2;
    wheelCount = 4;
}

class Human {
    armCount = 2;
    wheelCount = 2;

    getDuplicatedArmCount() {
        return this.armCount * 2;
    }
}

const car = new Car();

const carCopy = copy<Car>(car); // 1
const humanCopy = copy<Human>(car); // 2
const humanCopyAndCast = copy(car) as Human; // 3

console.log(humanCopy.getDuplicatedArmCount());
console.log(humanCopyAndCast.getDuplicatedArmCount()); // 4
```

This is a function that (poorly) copys an object. Obviously, when copying something, the result will be of the same type as the original. That's what the generic definition of `T` says.

Now when you compile this code, you'll see that

- 1) is just fine,
- 2) gives a compiler error as you're trying to copy a car, but expect a human at the end, with a `getDuplicatedArmCount` method,
- but with 3), by basically telling the compiler you're more clever than it, you don't get that error while compiling and will have a run-time issue instead in 4) that could easily be avoided.

**Update**: Updated the example to contain a method `getDuplicatedArmCount` to showcase the problem with vanilla TypeScript settings as well.

Comment: Are you sure ? 
Both created a compile error: 
For 3. `Conversion of type 'Car' to type 'Human' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other.`
For 2.  `Argument of type 'Car' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Human'` 

But it will compile and run and print "undefined"

Comment: With my standard tsc, that's the behavior – but it might be that I have some awkward tsconfig values from one of our projects still set.

Comment: I checked it out with vanilla TypeScript settings, and modified the example to provoke the same issue with that, too. You can try the updated code.